# logical test if object is a directory

Tags: r

Let's say I just created this directory and file:

```
dir.create("foo")
cat("bar", file="bar")

#both files exist:

file.exists("foo")
file.exists("bar")
```

I want to test both foo and bar to test logically if they are directories or not.  If something is a directory I want to be able to put other files in it.  If the item is not a directory I want to use `stop` but don't know of how test.

Poking around a bit got me to:

```
file.info("foo", "bar")
.Internal(file.info(fn <- c("foo", "bar")))
```

Which both give me the info I'm after but the `.Internal` use seems to be using a logical test of sorts for directory (meaning more efficient), but I can't figure out how. What is `file.info` using to test if the object is a directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want `file_test`?

```
file_test("-d", c("foo", "bar"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: As for how `file.info` **really** works, that's in the C function called by `.Internal(file.info)`, [`do_fileinfo`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/platform.c#L772) -- but I'm guessing (?) that that's not what you're actually wanting...

Comment: @TylerRinker -- Glad that helped. Rather than trying to memorize all of R's `file`-related functions, I often find myself doing `apropos("^file")`. It misses some, but gives a good starting list ;)

Answer (score 3):

`file.info` is obviously platform dependent and uses `_wstati64` on Windows and `stat` on Linux. See https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/platform.c